# Fancybox3 multiple links to same gallery without duplication

Tags: fancybox

I have a gallery of images and a bunch of links to it. However images are duplicated.

Code example:

```
<a data-fancybox="group" href="foto-1.jpg" ><img src="thumb1.jpg" /></a>
<a data-fancybox="group" href="foto-2.jpg" ></a>
<a data-fancybox="group" href="foto-3.jpg" ></a>

<a data-fancybox="group" href="foto-1.jpg" >Show More Images</a>
```

This cause image duplication in gallery.

How can I make a multiple links to the same object without duplications in Fancybox3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, for example, replace

`<a data-fancybox="group" href="foto-1.jpg" >Show More Images</a>`

with something like this:

```
<a id="more" href="foto-1.jpg" >Show More Images</a>

<script>
    $("#more").on('click', function() {
        $('[data-fancybox="group"]').eq(0).trigger('click');

        return false;
    });
</script>
```